# eclipse/android app: create from source

Tags: android, eclipse

i am new to android development and need some help. I like to create a project from existing source code. The project has to main folders:

> PAndroid
> with a /src folder
>
> PCore with a /src folder

i opened eclipse, selected new project / android / android project from existing code that works great. Second i tried to do the same with the PCore folder but  browsing this folders didnt find any projects to import. The PCore folder contains some core fails, that will also be used in other programs. How can i add these files to my project PAndroid?

I tried to create a java project for PCore this works. But if i run the app i got this error:

```
 05-07 11:29:07.519: E/dalvikvm(25837): Could not find class
 org.pandroid.android.core.Lists', referenced from method
 org.pandroid.android.net.home.ListsRemoteHome.getListPerformed
```

The class "`org.pandroid.android.core.Lists`" is included in the core files. Maybe the reference of a java project dosnt work.

EDIT:
If i run the app on Android 2.2 (virtual device) it runs without any errors. But why?

Answer (score 0):

If the eclipse can't find the project itself...just create a new project and copy the files  into src folder of that new project..

Comment: eclipse find the project and the core files. There are no errors in eclipse. I get the error running the project on the device (or virtual device) first

Answer (score 0):

The better way for referencing the java project in the android one is:

1. Go to the **Properties** of the android project, select **Java Build Path**
2. **Add** button and select the project (in your case PCore). In order to do this you need to have the project opened in the workspace.